# Windows application crash .dmp file analysis in visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, debugging, crash-dumps

To get the dump file (for crashes) I am using the userModeProcessorDumper.exe. Now the question is how to read this file (to see the stack information). Regarding this I have couple of questions

- Yes I know I can use WinDbg (related tools) to analyze the .dmp file. My question is - Can this be analyzed in Visual Studio? To be more specific - I am having Visual Studio Enterprise Edition 6 - In this particular pack - can the .dmp file be opened for analysis.

If Yes, Please help me with steps.

I see in web advice to use Visual Studio 2XXX version. So I am feeling that the same cannot be done using VS Enterprise Edition.

- The application is built on MinGW, even these application - can we analyze in Visual Studio (what ever is the edition - i.e Visual Studio 2XXX or VS Enterprise Edition X.Y)? Should I take care of any additional setting for this.

Any material link on this topic would be very helpful to me.

Thanks a lot in advance for your advice.

---

PS : My application is a C++ based application.

Comment: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/postmortemdebug_standalone1.aspx) is for VS.NET (version 7), but IIRC it is almost exactly the same procedure in VS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remembered, VS6 cannot be used to debug dumps. It's been a while since I last used it, and trying to verify me memory I came across a workaround that might allow you to debug those dumps after all: [Visual C++ 6, and post-mortem (crash dump) debugging](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=884017).

I don't have VC6 at hand, and have no idea if this really works. Other than that, I feel for you... There are IDEs so much better than VC6. Hope this inability gives you the push towards an upgrade. Debugging dumps is really easy with VC7 and above.